# What is a good system/hardware utility to show what type of memory I have?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware, system

I want some new memory for my computer and I can't find out what type of memory my computer uses and needs.  When I was using Windows I used Belarc to find out what hardware was on the computer.  Now that I am using ubuntu I am not sure what to use.  I also used Glary utilities.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo lshw -C memory` reveals following information on my machine:

```
sudo lshw -C memory 
[sudo] password for stefan: 
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 0208 (01/31/2005)
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 448KiB
       capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1b
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 1GiB
       capacity: 3GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: PartNum0
          vendor: Manufacturer0
          physical id: 0
          serial: SerNum0
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 512MiB
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: PartNum1
          vendor: Manufacturer1
          physical id: 1
          serial: SerNum1
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 512MiB
          width: 64 bits
```

Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes that was wonderful thank you.  My dad has been getting on me to find this out.

Comment: lshw is an acronym for 'list hardware'. Together with the switch -html you can produce an static html-file, and put it to your favourites in the browser. Of course, in case of defect or new hardware, you need to update the file manually.

Answer (score 4):

Try [hardinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardinfo) [image: Install hardinfo].

Alternatively, you can install it from a terminal using the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

It hasn't been updated recently, but it works well still (except for finding system temperature), and is graphical.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Sysinfo](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-see-your-system-information-in-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-using-sysinfo.html) is perfect for your need

To install it, type `sudo apt-get install sysinfo` in a terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program called "ailurus". Much like ubuntu tweak but also shows hardware information.

Comment: Can you add information about How to install "ailurus"? I didn't find it in Standard repository.